# Eating space before a command

Tags: spacing, macros

If I have a `\newcommand*{\foo}{foo}` it will 'eat' space after it. Is there a way to tell it to eat space before, so that the result of e.g. `bar \foo bar` would be 'barfoobar'?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can define `\foo` to `\unskip` before `foo` and gobble spaces afterward using `\ignorespaces`:

```
\newcommand*{\foo}{\leavevmode\unskip foo\ignorespaces}
```

The latter is not needed if you're using in-line. Note that forced spaces after `\foo` are still adhered to:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\foo}{\leavevmode\unskip foo\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
Here is~\foo some text \foo~with spaces\foo{}and nothing\ \foo\ else.
\end{document}
```

`\leavevmode` prevents oddities around the start of a paragraph.

Comment: +1 although you might want to put `\leavevmode` at the start or it will have an interesting effect at the start of a paragraph. Also no that neither `\unskip` nor `\ignorespaces` works by _expansion_ so technically doesn't answer the question as asked (but may answer the OP's real problem).

Comment: Fair point. I don't need it to work by expansion. I've edited the question.

Comment: Is there any way to remove also forced whitespace before the command, so that `bar\quad\foo bar` would also produce 'barfoobar'?