# Change the parentheses for other symbol in the first appearance of an acronym with acro package

Tags: acronyms, acro, parentheses

in the `acro` package the first appearance of the acronym is something like:

> deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA)

I would like to know if there is a way to change the parentheses for `-`, or `,` to do something like:

> deoxyribonucleic acid -DNA-
>
> deoxyribonucleic acid, DNA,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{acro}
%
\DeclareAcronym{DNA}{
short=DNA,
long=deoxyribonucleic acid
}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms\par
%
How it looks: \acf{DNA}\par
%
How I want: deoxyribonucleic acid -DNA- or
deoxyribonucleic acid, DNA,
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) allows you to define a custom first-style appearance, for the dashes case, it's sufficient to use `\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{dashes}{inline}{brackets=--}` which takes the default `inline` style and uses `-` and `-` instead of `(` and `)` toe enclose the short form.
For the comma variant, there's a space which [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) inserts by default which needs to then be removed for which [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135986/106162) does the job and therefore more bracing is required, with `\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{commas}{inline}{brackets-type={{\leavevmode\unskip,\space}{,}}}`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{DNA}{
short=DNA,
long=deoxyribonucleic acid,
first-style=dashes
}
\DeclareAcronym{DNAtwo}{
short=DNA,
long=deoxyribonucleic acid,
first-style=commas
}
\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{dashes}{inline}{
brackets-type=--
}
\DeclareAcroFirstStyle{commas}{inline}{
brackets-type={{\leavevmode\unskip,\space}{,}}
}

\begin{document}
\printacronyms

How it looks: \acf{DNA}

How it looks: \acf{DNAtwo}

How I want: deoxyribonucleic acid -DNA- or
deoxyribonucleic acid, DNA,
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Hi, by the way, how to set `first-style` globally?

Comment: @DangeRS2 have you looked at `\acsetup`?